# How to copy and save the mhtml content?

Tags: python, google-chrome, mhtml

I use the python script to read and save the mhtml content which is saved by Chrome.

```
with open(file_path, 'r+') as mht:
    text = mht.read() 
    with open('/Users/mac/Downloads/new.mht', 'w') as mht2:
        mht2.write(text)
```

The content of the files are identical. But when I tried to open the new document with Chrome, the page is blank and there is an error "Malformed multipart archive: ..." in console.

Why is this happening? Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I had compared the hex code of the two files, I found python script change line breaks from `0A0D` which is '\r\n' to `0D` '\n'. Force python keeps the line breaks:

```
with open('/Users/mac/Downloads/new.mht', 'w', newline='\r\n') as mht2:
    mht2.write(text)
```

will do.